# Jquery not reading dynamically added class

Tags: jquery, class

I am building a on click drop down menu. When the link is clicked the drop down comes down then when anything but the dropmenu is touched the dropmenu slides back up. The only thing left is to make the dropmenu slide up when the link is clicked again. I have added a .act class to the link so that I can single it out from the other links (so that I may then hide it when it is clicked ) but jquery isnt reading this added class. Here is my code.

```
function headerNav() {
  $('header nav a').bind('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
  });

  // change
  $('header nav a').on('click', function() {
      changeNavCont($(this));
  });

  //show
  $('header nav a').on('click', function() {
     $('.dropDownMenu').addClass('show');
     $(this).addClass('act');
  });

  //hide
$('header nav a.act').on('click', function() {
        $('.dropDownMenu').removeClass('show');
        $('header nav a').removeClass('act');
});  

  $(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if (($(e.target).closest('header nav').length === 0)) {
        $('.dropDownMenu').removeClass('show');
        $('header nav a').removeClass('act');
    }
  });
}

function changeNavCont($this) {

  $('header nav a').removeClass('act');
  $this.addClass('act');
  var show = $this.attr('href');
  $('.dropDownMenu article').removeClass('show');
  $('.dropDownMenu article.' + show).addClass('show'); 

}
```

Comment: That's a mess, should be more like -> https://jsfiddle.net/o4o5yave/

Answer (score 1):

You are using `$this` on your show function, but $this isn't defined in that function.  It looks like you should use `$(this)` making it:

```
//show
$('header nav a').on('click', function() {
   $('.dropDownMenu').addClass('show');
   $(this).addClass('act');
});
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you for the answer. Good catch on the $(this) but Jquery still isnt picking up the added .act class. I updated the code above with your correction and added the hide function im using to hide the drop down when the link with the .act class is clicked.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle with your html on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Not at the moment but ill work on it and get back to you. thank you for the help